# React get meta tags from WP API

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-helmet

I'm using react helmet server side and I am trying to get the meta tags from a Wordpress API, like post excerpt, image, title and so on. I'm using axios to make a request to the WP API.

React Helmet is working, but everytime I try to get the tags from the WP API via state it toggles me a re-render and does not updates it on Open Graph Object Debugger.

Here's the code i'm using:

```
    constructor(props) {    
       this.state = { posts : [] };
    }

   _getPosts(){
    axios.get( URL.path + URL.posts + '?slug=' + this.props.match.params.id )
    .then( res => {
        this.setState({ posts: res.data });
    });
}
  componentWillMount(){
        this._getPosts();
   }
    render(){
        return(
            <Helmet>
               <meta name="description" content={this.state.posts.title} />
               <meta property="og:image" content){this.state.posts.featured_image} />
            </Helmet>
        );
    }
```